# Visual Studio: Disable Automatic Initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I code my C++ assignments in Visual Studio Enterprise. However, I noticed that when I ran my code in linux to check on different platforms, that I would have errors because visual studio, regardless of what you do with your variables, initializes all variables to zero. for instance, I forgot to set the head pointer in a Linked List exercise to nullptr and VS still ran fine, but linux did not. I really want to be able to catch these errors earlier, so is there a way to disable in VS this automatic initialization?

Thanks

Comment: VS only does that in debug builds.  Test your release builds.

Comment: As I recall the problem is more the opposite, that g++ intends to provide "bear's help" by zeroing local variables. Anyway the solution is to adopt more rigorous programming practices.

Comment: @Y. Lou  Usually compilers issue a warning when an uninitialized variable with the automatic storage duration is used. Look whether you can change the level of warnings for MS VC++.

Comment: Try compiling in release mode. Also consider making Linux your primary build platform. Run your program through valgrind to catch lots of errors. Compile with -Wall -Wextra -Werror and you're mostly set.

Comment: @n.m. The devil has better songs.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf No need to give up anything. It's OK to edit code in Visual Studio, nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score 3):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx

Have you tried disabling SDL?

Right clikc your Project => Properties => C/C++ => Code Generation => Security Check => Disable Security Check.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped catch my nullptr error!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve few of issues using visual studio settings.

Go to `ProjectProperties -> C/C++ -> General -> Treat Warning as Error`
and set it to `True`

I may not solve your problem entirely but will help you to catch few error beforehand.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also up the warning level to `/W4`.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the underlying issue, calls to [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) are what is causing the inconsistency (Note that `operator new` uses `malloc` internally). In the  documentation for `malloc`, it explicitly states that the memory is not initialized. However, the OS/runtime may intervene and initialize the memory automatically, as is the case for VS debug runtime, but this shouldn't be relied upon in cross platform development.

To have consistent behavior, you could instead allocate memory with [`calloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) (and override `operator new` to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`). Of course, this means you'll be using some cycles in your program to initialize the memory. Alternatively, you could fill the allocated memory from `malloc` with 'garbage', which is also a popular strategy for finding memory initialization issues.

In terms of detecting it without replacing the allocator, in Visual Studio, ensure that you have "Basic Runtime Checks" set to "Both /RTC1" or "Uninitialized variables /RTCu". This should give you a break in the debugger when a member is used without being initialized, in certain situations, although it's no guarantee. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx) for more information on the situations in which this detection will occur.